# How can I get the difference of two JSON's in C#

Tags: c#, json, compare, element, difference

today I come to ask about how I can compare two different JSONs, and lets say the first JSON has 7 elements, but the second JSON has 9 elements.

How can I make my program determine which 2 elements are the new elements?

Here is the code I have tried but it hasn't worked very well.

```
                bool check = false;

                foreach (var item in jsonTwo["contentItems"])
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in jsonOne["contentItems"])
                    {
                        if (item["contentFields"]["title"].ToString() == item2["contentFields"]["title"].ToString())
                        {
                            check = true;
                        }
                        else
                        { check = false; }
                    }

                    if (check == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item["contentFields"]["title"].ToString());
                    }
                }
```

All help appreciated!!

Comment: you can use `JsonDiffer `: https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonDiffer  package for compare between json objects.   usage like this ->  var j1 = JToken.Parse(Read(jsonOne));
 var j2 = JToken.Parse(Read(jsonTwo));

 var diff = JsonDifferentiator.Differentiate(j1,j2);

Comment: Thanks for the package @AmirhosseinAzhdari, its good but the issue is, if there are two different elements that are in two different indexes in an array, it will detect everything in between those elements as a difference, even if they are not a difference.

Comment: yes, its compare json objects Only in three modes,  ‍`Does not exist`, `It has a different value`,  ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`Is extra‍`.

Comment: Try this package, which has more features than the previous package, `https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonDiffPatch.Net/
Which I do not think it is detect difference between value of an array with different indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Hy how about this?

```
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name}-{City}-{Age}"; 
        }
    }

    public class UserEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
    {
        public bool Equals(User x, User y)
        {
            return x.Age == y.Age && x.City == y.City;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(User obj)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonArray = new List<string>()
        {
            @"{name: ""John"", age: 31, city: ""New York""}",
            @"{name: ""John2"", age: 31, city: ""New York""}",
            @"{name: ""John3"", age: 33, city: ""New York""}",
        };

        var users = jsonArray.Select(m => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(m)).ToList();

        var groups = users.GroupBy(m => m, new UserEqualityComparer()).ToList();


        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```